# Selenium complains input of type checkbox is not clickable (element click intercepted)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to uncheck this checkbox with Selenium:

[image]

**EDIT: per request, the relevant HTML code from the picture is the following:**

```
<label class="video-privacy-label ct-label-compact">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="$ctrl.isVideoOrganization" ng-change="$ctrl.changeVideoPermissions()" aria-checked="true" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" aria-invalid="false">
    <span class="ng-binding">Allow everyone in your company to view this video</span> 
</label>
```

using this code **(per request, UPDATED with three more lines)**:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys("my/file/path")
time.sleep(4) 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//v-pane[contains(@id, 'permissions')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(@class, 'video-privacy-label')]//input[@type='checkbox']").click()
```

but in the last line, Selenium complains that:

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="checkbox" ng-model="$ctrl.isVideoOrganization" ng-change="$ctrl.changeVideoPermissions()" aria-checked="true" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" aria-invalid="false"> is not clickable at point (301, 731). Other element would receive the click: <div
class="video-edit-pane-content permissions-pane">...</div>
```

How can I uncheck this checkbox? I'm using chromedriver

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB the screenshot is neither code or error. Code and error are in code brackets in the question

Comment: The screenshot contains HTML code, and that is the code we need to see.

Comment: Can you add your code? This could be caused by a number of issues, pop ups, screen size differences if in headless mode, wrong xpath, etc.

Comment: I have updated the question with more html context and the relevant html in code brackets and with the three more lines of code that I call before the click